# C# RegEx pattern for scheduler (date / time alike pattern matcher)

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Can someone guide me in the direction on how to get a RegEx pattern matching the following possibilities for C#?:

- RegEx using 4 parameters
- First 2 params can get the star (*) character as value
- 1st param, if not a *, needs to be an int between (including) 0 and 6 (single digit)
- 2st param, if not a *, needs to be an int between (including) 01 and 31 (double digit)
- 3rd param needs to be an int between (including) 00 and 23 (double digit)
- 4th param needs to be an int of 00, 15, 30 or 45 (double digit)

I also need to check if a given string (same format as mentioned) matches the current date time in the same format.
If data is "* 5 15 30", and current date formatted is "2 5 15 30", matching check would tell me it matches.
If data is "0 5 15 30", and current date formatted is "2 5 15 30", matching check would tell me it doesn't matches.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you if your parameters are separated by some amount of white-space in the string:

```
(\*|[0-6])\s+(\*|[0-2]\d|3[01])\s+([01]\d|2[0-3])\s+(00|15|30|45)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Any idea how to do the matching with the current date formatted the same way?

Comment: @user706058 I do't see a way to do it with regex, but if you use this expression on the current date you could would have for parameters to match against. You would do a check like `if(4th matches), then if(3rd matches), then if(second is * or matches), then if(1st is * or matches) you have a match.` You could just do integer comparison on all your matches.